# Como executar java no prompt pelo Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, prompt

Eu fiz um código em java e nele eu uso "\r" que só funciona no prompt e gostaria de saber como executar esse código no prompt pelo próprio eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directamente, através do *Eclipse*, não é possível.
Terá de exportar a aplicação como *"Runnable JAR file"* e executá-la numa *janela de comando*:

Clique com o botão do lado direito do rato sobre o seu projecto:
Escolha **Runnable JAR file** e clique em <kbd>Next</kbd>.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seleccione a **Launche configuration** e indique o local onde gravar o *jar*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

Para executar abra uma *janela de comando* onde guardou o *jar* e execute o seguinte comando:

```
java -jar nomePrograma.jar
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]